# Estimate Mean of the Distribution using Pytorch NN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I need some help with my implementation, I have been struggling for a while and not been able to figure out a solution .

I am working on a problem wherein part of the problem I am required to compute the mean of the data coming in ( as the data gets available) it to compute mean of the distribution.

I have N sets of distributions,N is finite and each distribution will have its own mean.

I came across this simple implementation and implemented for N =1 using for loop, for the original problem N > 1, therefore I end up using PyTorch NN, will go over it later in the post.

First, the basic implementation uses for loop for N = 1, and data is the data coming in and the goal is to compute its mean. Using for loop just for demonstration, as I have all the data available to me right now, for true online implementation, data will be flowing in step by step. For this problem I created 300 random numbers.

N is an integer and data is float.

```
for i in range (300):

mean_init = 0

a = 0.95

Mean_new = a * mean_init + (1 - a)* data(i)

Mean_init = mean_new
```

The results for the mean estimate is below :

Blue is: true mean and black is the estimate of the mean from the for loop above.

The estimate eventually converges to true mean.
[image]

Since I want to use a similar implementation using NN , I decided to rearrange the equations to compute Loss. Just for a recap :

New_mean = a * old_mean + (1-a)*data

in for loop old mean is initiated to mean_init to start

So Los is : new_mean – old_mean = a * old_mean + (1-a)*data – old_mean

Rearranging above

**Loss = (1-a)[-old_mean + data ]**

Now, for my original problem since N > 1, for eg 2000, therefore I have 2000 distributions for which I need to compute the mean. I am using Pytorch NN neural net. With NN implementation my results are way off and not even close, my NN is not even learning I also tried with the same data, and N = 1 ( meaning learning mean of the just 1 distribution)

Inputs: N and data ( data corresponds to the N for which mean is computed)

Output: mean of the data.

The loss function is similar to the above.

**Loss = (1-a)[-old_mean + data ]**

NN class

```
class NN(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, hidden_layer_size):

super().__init__()

torch.manual_seed(args.seed)

self.hidden_layer_size = hidden_layer_size

self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, self.hidden_layer_size)

self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_layer_size, 1)

def forward(self, x):

output = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))

output = self.fc2(output)

return output
```

**NN Train class**

```
class NN_Train(object):

def __init__(self):

torch.manual_seed(args.seed)

self.ucb = NN(args.UCB_HIDDEN_LAYER_SIZE).to(device)

self.criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

self.optimizer = optim.Adam(params=self.ucb.parameters(), lr=args.UCB_LEARNING_RATE)

def UCB_calc(self, N, data, episode):

self.optimizer = optim.Adam(

params=self.ucb.parameters(), lr=args.UCB_LEARNING_RATE)

N = torch.Tensor(actions).to(device)

data = torch.Tensor(data).to(device)

x = [N,data]

x = torch.Tensor(x).to(device)

mean = self.ucb(x)

loss = (1-args.UCB_FILTER) * (data - mean)

loss = torch.Tensor(loss_ucb).to(device)

print(loss_ucb)

self.optimizer.zero_grad()

loss.backward()

return(mean)
```

output using NN orange is true mean above and blue is computed, way off

r/pytorch - Estimate mean using NN pytorch

[image]

**Some background to the problem**
The data input to the model is coming from some simulation, just to give some context . There is a separate algorithm that commands certain actions/inputs to the simulation and the simulation provides an output. The action/input to this simulation is discretized in 2000 steps ranging from 0, 1 ,2 .... 2000. Each of these actions corresponds to different output given the states the simulation is in. And the goal of my exercise above is to compute the mean of these outputs for each action . Following show an example.

Hope this provides some context and help clarify it more . Do you see any mistakes that stand out in the code?ulation is in and therefore goal is to compute the mean of this distribution for all the actions . Each of these 2000 actions will have a distribution and the goal is to compute the mean of this distribution as the simulation makes the output available (every step).

Hope this provide some context and help clarify it more . Do you see any mistakes that stand out in the code?

for eg: the same action let's say 1000 will have a distribution of outputs depending on the state the simulation is in and therefore the goal is to compute the mean of this distribution for all the actions .